# How to extract substrings in R using stringr::str_match

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I have the following two strings:

```
x <- "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.Adipose"
y <- "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.combined.HMSC-ad"
```

With this regex I have no problem capturing parts of `x`

```
> stringr::str_match(x,"(\\w+):(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)")
     [,1]                                [,2]   [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     
[1,] "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.Adipose" "chr1" "625000" "635000" "BB_162" "Adipose"
```

What I want to do is with `y` to obtain this

```
     [,1]                                [,2]   [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     
[1,] "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.combined.HMSC-ad"  "chr1" "625000" "635000" "BB_162" "HMSC-ad"
```

With my current regex and apply for `y` I get this instead:

```
   [,1]                                 [,2]   [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]      
[1,] "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.combined" "chr1" "625000" "635000" "BB_162" "combined"
```

How can I generalize my regex so that it can deal with both `x` and `y`?

**Update**

S.Kalbar, your regex gave this:

```
> stringr::str_match(y,"(\\w+):(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)(?:\\.([A-Za-z-]+))?")
     [,1]                                         [,2]   [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]       [,7]     
[1,] "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.combined.HMSC-ad" "chr1" "625000" "635000" "BB_162" "combined" "HMSC-ad"
> stringr::str_match(x,"(\\w+):(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)(?:\\.([A-Za-z-]+))?")
     [,1]                                [,2]   [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]      [,7]
[1,] "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.Adipose" "chr1" "625000" "635000" "BB_162" "Adipose" NA
```

What' I'd like to get is this for `y`:

```
                                          [,1]     [,2]   [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]        
[1,] "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.combined.HMSC-ad" "chr1" "625000" "635000" "BB_162" "HMSC-ad"
```

And this for `x`:

```
                                   [,1]  [,2]   [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]      
[1,] "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.Adipose" "chr1" "625000" "635000" "BB_162" "Adipose"
```

Comment: For general regex problems it can help to play with your examples on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: `(\w+):(\d+)-(\d+)\.(\w+)(?:\.\w+)?(?:\.([A-Za-z-]+))`

[RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/TguAYS/5)

Comment: @S.Kalbar It's seems that the answer is incorrect for `x`, it get `Adipos` without ending `e`. Beside please give example in R code.

Comment: @S.Kalbar as pointed in my OP. I look for `one` regex that can take care for both `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the engines some tokens to split on:

```
(?:(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d))|(?:\\.combined\\.)|[.:]+
```

Broken down, this says:

```
(?:(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d))  # a dash between numbers
|                     # or
(?:\\.combined\\.)    # .combined. literally
|                     # or
[.:]+                 # one of . or :
```

---

In `R` using `str_split()`:

```
library(stringr)

x <- c("chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.Adipose", "chr1:625000-635000.BB_162.combined.HMSC-ad")
str_split(x, '(?:(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d))|(?:\\.combined\\.)|[.:]+', simplify = TRUE)
```

Which yields

```
     [,1]   [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     
[1,] "chr1" "625000" "635000" "BB_162" "Adipose"
[2,] "chr1" "625000" "635000" "BB_162" "HMSC-ad"
```